# How do I calculate the inductivity of a capacitor with an impedance-frequency graph?

Tags: capacitor

Lets say I want to calculate the inductivity of one of these capacitors.

[image]

I know every capacitor has an ESR ESL

$$ Z = R + \frac {1}{jwC} + jwL $$

Can I use this formula? Im obviously missing the R though could anyone help me here?

Comment: Just plug a point well after the resonance into $$Z=jwL$$ also, R is simply the impedance in the resonance point.

Comment: looks like their test jig could have about 0.8 nH inductance, regardless of the capacitor tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one of those impedance graphs has a minimum point, that's the point where the reactive components (L and C) of the capacitor cancel each other out (causing a resonance).

\$\frac {1}{jwC} = -jwL\$ at that resonance point, so given the capacitance, you should be able to calculate the parasitic series inductance using this equation.